# Angle between 2 planes

Tags: r, geometry

I have the equation of a plane. I would like to obtain the angle between this plane and the plane formed by the x and y axes.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your equation of the plane is in form of

```
 ax + by + cz + d = 0
```

hence the equation of x-y plane is

```
z = 0
```

then by using this function it will return the angle in degree

```
ang_degree <- function(a , b , c){
    acos(abs(c)/sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2))*180/pi
}
```

if you want it in radian remove `*180/pi`

Answer (score 1):

Given the equations of the two planes:

```
A1x + B1y + C1z + D1 = 0
A2x + B2y + C2z + D2 = 0
```

where A, B, C and D are the plane coefficients, then the angle between the two planes is given by the following [formula](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/angle-between-two-planes/):

[image]

The equation of the second plane will be much simpler, i.e. `z = 0`.

Comment: Thank you, it may sound stupid but I couldn't figure out the equation of the second plan. It sounds easy now.

Answer (score 0):

The angle between two planes is the same as the angle between the normals of these planes.

If **ax + by + cz + d = 0** is the plane equation then **(a,b,c)** is a normal of this plane.

Then use the dot product:

```
dot_product(normal1, normal2) = cos(the_angle) * norm(normal1) * norm(normal2)
```

Then `acos` to get the angle.